# Why two counts in the same query are not working

Tags: postgresql, join, count

I have four tables. 
Category, Product, Sale and Review. Category has one or more products, a product has one or more review and a product is in one or more sales.
Now I need to know how many products belongs to every category, the average score for each category and the total of  sales for each category
I know how to get them with:

Sales by Category

```
SELECT category.name, COUNT(sale.id_product) as sale
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN category on category.id_category=product.id_category
LEFT OUTER JOIN sale on sale.id_product =product.id_product
Group by category.name
```

Average Score by Category

```
SELECT category.name, round(CAST(AVG(review.score as numeric),2) 
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN review on review.id_product = product.id_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN category on category.id_category=product.id_category
GROUP BY category.name
```

Count of reviews by Category

```
SELECT category.name, COUNT(review.id_product)
FROM category
LEFT OUTER JOIN product on category.id_category = product.id_category
Left outer join review on product.id_product = review.id_product
Group by category.name
```

Now that I want the three of them in the same query, it doesn't work 
I tried with:

```
SELECT category.name as category, 
COUNT(sale.id_product) as   sales,       
round(CAST(AVG(review.score as numeric),2) as average,               
COUNT(review.id_product) as totalreviews
FROM product
FULL OUTER JOIN category on category.id_category = product.id_category
FULL OUTER JOIN sale on product.id_product=sale.id_product
FULL OUTER JOIN review on product.id_product = review.id_product
GROUP BY category.name
```

EXAMPLE

Category

```
+---------------+-----+
| category      | id  |
+---------------+-----+
| category1     | 1   |
| category2     | 2   |
+---------------+-----+
```

Product

```
+---------------+-----+---------------+-------+
| productid     | id  | id_category   | price |       
+---------------+-----+---------------+-------+
| Product1      | 1   |      1        |   10  |
| Product2      | 2   |      2        |   12  |
+---------------+-----+---------------+-------+
```

REVIEW

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| reviewid      | idProduct | Score         |      
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1          | 1         |      10       |
|    2          | 1         |      9        |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

SALE

```
 +---------------+------------+
 | idsale        | idproduct  |
 +---------------+------------+
 | sale1         |     1      |
 | sale2         |     1      |
 +---------------+------------+
```

What I want

```
 +---------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
 | category      | sales  | average score   | Reviews |       
 +---------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
 | category1     | 2      |      9.5        |   2     |
 | category2     | 0      |                 |         |
 +---------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message

Comment: can you provide ddls for these three tables.

Comment: Mi "it doesn't work" means that it doesn't give me the expected result. I did a little example :)

Comment: Please, fix question. In sql join by `product.id_product`. But in table product have `productid` and `id` columns.

Comment: The reason 2 sales and 2 reviews for same product. Full join will return 4 lines. What is not what you want. In this case for count need select distinct values. F.ex. `count(sales.id)`. Not sure about score.